# OpenID Connect: Is it an error to request scope openid with response_type token

Tags: openid-connect, oidc-client-js

There is a misbehaving OpenID Connect "compatible" iDP (it shall remain nameless for now) - it throws an error when using scope openid and any response_type that includes id_token. That is surely a bug which has been reported.

That same iDP also returns the id_token in the implicit flow when the scope includes openid and the response_type is simply "token". This messes up the widely used oidc-client npm package, which reports an error "Not expecting id_token in response" - which, according to the OIDC spec, is strictly, correct

But this has brought up an interesting question:

Given the basic premise from section 1 of the OIDC spec:

> OpenID Connect implements authentication as an extension to the OAuth
>   2.0 authorization process. Use of this extension is requested by Clients by including the openid scope value in the Authorization
>   Request.

and that section 3.2.2.1 says

> NOTE: While OAuth 2.0 also defines the token Response Type value for
>   the Implicit Flow, OpenID Connect does not use this Response Type,
>   since no ID Token would be returned.

should it therefore be an error to use the two together? Or should the fact that openid is in the scope cause the implementation to "add" id_token to the response_type of the implicit flow by default?

Answer (score 1):

As I see, OpenID Connect provider should return an error. It should use error code `invalid_request` which is defined by **[OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2.1)** for implicit error response.

> The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.

But from specification perspective, error response is not required/mandatory. It simply say response type with token is not valid.

> NOTE: While OAuth 2.0 also defines the token Response Type value for the Implicit Flow, OpenID Connect does not use this Response Type, since no ID Token would be returned.

I think mentioned OpenID Connect provider only respect scope value and serve request as an OpenID Connect request. Thus you get a id token in response.